# Deleting items in ReactJS, using useState and useContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context, use-context

As a fairly new addict to programming, I'm stuck with a simple app that lists items. Adding items, is OK. But as for deleting one item, I just can't figure out how to implement this function. Now on clicking an item the whole array of items is deleted. I have tried to put the deleteItem function in other files, but I seem to have mixed up the references.

ItemContext.js:

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';
import { v1 as uuidv1 } from 'uuid';
export const ItemContext = createContext();

export const ItemProvider = (props) => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {
      name: "Red Beans",
      amount: 23,
      id: uuidv1()
    },
    {
      name: "Nuts for Bunnies",
      amount: 33,
      id: uuidv1()
    },
    {
      name: "Chopped Tomatoes",
      amount: 2,
      id: uuidv1() 
    }
]);
  return ( 
      <ItemContext.Provider value={[items, setItems]} >
        {props.children}
      </ItemContext.Provider>
   );
}
```

AddItem.js:

```
    import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { ItemContext } from './ItemContext';

const AddItem = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState('');
  const [items, setItems] = useContext(ItemContext);

  const updateName = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value)
  }

  const updateAmount = (e) => {
    setAmount(e.target.value)
  }

  const addItem = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setItems(prevItems => [...prevItems, {name: name, amount: amount, key: items.id}])
  }

  return ( 
      <form className="new-item" onSubmit={addItem}>
        <input type="text" name="name" value={name} onChange={updateName} placeholder="Add a new item"/>
        <input type="text" name="amount" value={amount} onChange={updateAmount} placeholder="Amount"/>
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
   );
}
 
export default AddItem;
```

Item.js:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { ItemContext } from './ItemContext';

const Item = ({name, amount, /*deleteItem*/ }) => {
  const [id, setId] = useState('');
  const [items, setItems] = useContext(ItemContext);

  const deleteItem = (id) => {
    // const newItems = items.filter(item => items.id !== id);
    // setItems(newItems);
    const newItems = Object.assign([], ...items)
    items.splice(id, 1);
    setItems(newItems);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{name}</h3>
      <p>{amount}</p>
      <button onClick={() => deleteItem(items.id)} className="delete-btn">Delete</button>
    </div>
  );
}
 
export default Item;
```

ItemsList.js:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import Item from './Item';
import { ItemContext } from './ItemContext';
import { v1 as uuidv1 } from 'uuid';

const ItemsList = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useContext(ItemContext);
  const [id, setId] = useState('');

  const deleteItem = (id) => {
    // const newItems = items.filter(item => items.id !== id);
    // setItems(newItems);
    const newItems = Object.assign([], ...items)
    items.splice(id, 1);
    setItems(newItems);
  }

  return (
    <div className="items-list">
      {items.map(item => (
        <Item name={item.name} amount={item.amount} key={uuidv1()} deleteItem={deleteItem}/>
      ))}
    </div> 
   );
}
 
export default ItemsList;
```

Comment: `items.filter(item => items.id !== id)` should be sufficient for removing an element from array. You seem to have a lot of duplicated state and multiple delete handlers, this may be part of your problem. Which "state" is the real `items` state? Oh, wait, I see, you are pulling the `items` "state" from the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially you need to provide a valid initial value to the `ItemContext` context you are creating. Its signature should match what the context value will be. I suggest using an object instead of an array.

```
export const ItemContext = createContext({
  items: [],
  addItem: () => {},
  deleteItem: () => {}
});
```

Then define `addItem` and `deleteItem` handlers to include in the context value. You want to avoid exposing out the `setItems` state function directly so `ItemProvider` maintains control over the state invariant.

```
const initialState = [
  {
    name: "Red Beans",
    amount: 23,
    id: uuidv1()
  },
  {
    name: "Nuts for Bunnies",
    amount: 33,
    id: uuidv1()
  },
  {
    name: "Chopped Tomatoes",
    amount: 2,
    id: uuidv1()
  }
];

const ItemProvider = (props) => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(initialState);

  const addItem = (item) => setItems((items) => [...items, item]);
  const deleteItem = (id) =>
    setItems((items) => items.filter((item) => item.id !== id));

  const value = {
    items,
    addItem,
    deleteItem
  };

  return (
    <ItemContext.Provider value={value}>
      {props.children}
    </ItemContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Then destructure the `ItemContext` value where you are consuming it.

AddItem.js - Make sure to assign a new uuidV1 GUID for new items. I think this was your biggest issue, you were assigning `undefined` to a `key` property (`key: items.id`) instead of creating a new GUID for the `id` property.

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { ItemContext } from './ItemContext';

const AddItem = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState("");
  const { addItem } = useContext(ItemContext);

  const updateName = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value);
  };

  const updateAmount = (e) => {
    setAmount(e.target.value);
  };

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addItem({
      name: name,
      amount: amount,
      id: uuidv1() // <-- new GUID here!!
    });
  };

  return (
    <form className="new-item" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="name"
        value={name}
        onChange={updateName}
        placeholder="Add a new item"
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        name="amount"
        value={amount}
        onChange={updateAmount}
        placeholder="Amount"
      />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Item.js - Get `deleteItem` from the context and ensure to pass item `id` to component.

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { ItemContext } from './ItemContext';

const Item = ({ name, amount, id }) => {
  const { deleteItem } = useContext(ItemContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{name}</h3>
      <p>{amount}</p>
      <button onClick={() => deleteItem(id)} className="delete-btn">
        Delete
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

ItemsList.js - Set the React key to the current item `id` and also pass the `id` as a prop to `Item.

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import Item from './Item';
import { ItemContext } from './ItemContext';

const ItemsList = () => {
  const { items } = useContext(ItemContext);

  return (
    <div className="items-list">
      {items.map((item) => (
        <Item
          key={item.id} // <-- Static React key to item
          id={item.id} // <-- Pass id as prop for delete handler to use
          name={item.name}
          amount={item.amount}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

## Demo

[image: Edit deleting-items-in-reactjs-using-usestate-and-usecontext]

Comment: Thanks for your effort, really appreciate it. Now its much clearer for me how to structure this.

Comment: I tried to connect this project to a firebase database. But somehow I am still facing issues eg. the state is not updated immediately when I add a new item, and the delete function is not working. I tried copying the item component into the itemslist component, without success. I found out that I made an infinite loop in the useEffect. Now I fixed it, but not sure if it is ok. I just can't beleive that I cannot find the solution for a properly working simple app as this. Or perhaps I should add more useEffects somewhere. If you have the time can you look at my code if I upload it?